# soap client api call

Tags: php

Kindly any one explain how to give request and when hit the soap api url i want to get the response using soap client call.

Comment: `$array['key'] = 'value'` instead of pushing the values. Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an assign and an unset

```
 $your_array[$your_newkey] = $you_array[$your_oldkey];
 unset($arr[$your_oldkey]);
```

Comment: I have to return this renamed array key value pair in that array itself without using return .

Comment: for show you coul use `echo  $your_array[$_your_newkey];`   . and once you have assigned and unset the array is available as before the change